# WCF Datamember return depends on conditions

Tags: vb.net, wcf

Hi I got the class below, My problem is want to return the ResponseMsg to the user only the ResponseCode is not 00 otherwise it will not return to the user. How to do it. Please help. Thanks

```
<DataContract([Namespace]:="")>
Public Class LoginResponse
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property TerminalID As String
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property ReaderID As String
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property TransRef As String
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property TransDateTime As String
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property Timeout As Integer
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property ResponseCode As String
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property ResponseMsg As String
    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property Cryptogram As String
End Class
```

Comment: Whats the difficulty here?

Answer (score 0):

Just define a property for ResponseMsg like below

```
  Public Property ResponseMsg() As String
     Get
       if String.Compare(ResponseCode , "00") = 0 Then  
         Return m_lWidth
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
         m_lWidth = Value
    End Set
  End Property
```

Happy Coding :)